# on solving $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = cy$ in matlab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

The differential equation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = my$ has two solutions 
 $y = e^{\sqrt{m}x}$ and $y = e^{-\sqrt{m}x}$.

When I use ode45 (or any other IVP solver) in matlab, it always picks up $y = e^{\sqrt{m}x}$.

How do I make matlab pick the other solution, namely $y = e^{-\sqrt{m}x}$?

Comment: Please note that for the solution to be uniquely defined, you must impose two initial conditions. Otherwise, there are infinitely many solutions, depending on a parameter

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB does not pick $y = e^{\sqrt{m} x}$. Since $y_1 = e^{\sqrt{m} x}$ and $y_2 =  e^{-\sqrt{m} x}$ are both solutions, then the solution is the linear combination of both namely
$$y(x) = c_1 y_1(x) + c_2y_2(x)$$
Now, depending on the initial conditions you've passed ode45, $c_1,c_2$ will be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: initial conditions at x = 0 are same for both the solutions.  In general the solution can be $Ae^{\sqrt{m}x}$, with A completely arbitrary. So, specifying the initial value at certain x = x0, also may not help.

Comment: Intial condition $y(0) = c$, means that $c_1 + c_2 = c$. This means that you got infinitely many solutions lying on the hyperplane $c_1 + c_2 = c$. To uniquely determine $c_1,c_2$, you need another first order condition. Choices could be based on another value, say $y(1)  = d$ or on the derivative, say $y'(0) = d$. @Angela

Comment: Thanks. But I had to give the very precise initial conditions, then it works. A small random error in initial conditions (even 1% error), then the solution picks up $e^{\sqrt{m}x}$.  However, if I give the second derivative as $\sqrt{m}*dy/dx$ instead of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = my$ in the function handle to ode45, then  the result is more immune to errors in initial condition. Unfortunately, I cannot modify the way I define the second derivative in my actual problem. Do  you have any other thoughts here?

Comment: what are your initial conditions @Angela

Comment: For y = exp(-2x), I give the initial conditions y(0) = 1;and y'(0) = -2. If I give y'(0) = -1.99 or -2.01, then the solution explodes if I give y'' = 4y. If  however, I give y'' = -2y' in the function handle, then the solution does not explode.

Comment: @Angela : Yes, of course the solution will "explode", exponential functions have a rather "explosive" growth. In $0.99e^{-2x}+0.01e^{2x}$, the second term will dominate the first after $x=0.25\ln(99)=1.15$